# How likely is it that hyperspace could be used to bypass a planet's shields, and then land?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

> In The Force Awakens, Han uses hyperspace to mask 
>  the Millenium Falcon's entrance into a planet's atmosphere
>  and then manages to land the ship in one piece.

Just how likely (using sci fi physic allowances) is it that you could leave hyperspace within a planet's atmosphere and still be able to land a ship?

So that the point of the question is not lost, I'll use an analogy. There are many feats of piloting in movies like, say, **Top Gun**, that pilots forgive because..movies, and there are other things that they just flat out will tell you is not physically possible.

I'm asking if landing on a planet after leaving hyperspace *in atmosphere* would be one of those things, even in a universe where sci fi physics are real, that we would have to forgive *because movies* (ie, it is not possible but makes for a good movie feat) or if we would agree that such a thing could be possible...on a good day...as long as we were really good pilots.

EDIT:
Maybe it's my wording.

In this question, I am playing the skeptic from within the Star Wars universe. I accept that the Star Wars universe is real, I accept that the Resistance did what it did. but I am doubting the details of how they were done. For instance,

> Rey thought Luke Skywalker was just a legend.

Would people, years after TFA, believe this hyperspace story was but a legend, too?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield as I state in the question, I am asking for an answer that assumes hyperspace and the related physics are real. I want to know how big a "big fish" story this would be, in universe.

Comment: @T.J.L. your comment is actually exactly what i was asking for (the part about gravity wells preventing hyperspace travel). I guess I am asking for people to assume TFA is a story we are hearing from within the Star Wars universe, and whether we would believe this feat to actually be possible. If you turn you comment into an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: Title: How did Han bypass a planet's shields in hyperspace and then land? ... Body: Gravity wells prevent hyperspace travel, so what's the in-universe explanation for how this trick was achieved?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Mazura. That would have been a better way for me to ask this question, clearly.

Comment: i created a new question based on @Mazura's suggested syntax. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114924/how-did-han-bypass-a-planets-shields-in-hyperspace-and-then-land

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking Legends canon into account, there's room for doubt that this would work at all. The [gravity wells](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_well) generated by stars and planets prevent hyperspace travel. The same phenomena is used with [gravity well projectors](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_well_projector), artificial gravity field generators to create hyperspace [interdictors](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Interdictor_cruiser), vessels capable of preventing ships from entering hyperspace or knocking them out of it.

In Disney Canon, the evidence that it's possible is right there on the screen. The film defines the limitations of the science.